# Equivalent of pgp command in bouncy castle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

Does anyone know what will be the equivalent of following command (GnuPG 2.17.2) in bouncy castle in Java?

```
gpg -e -r "recipient" --output output.gpg input.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a certificate and private key

```
public static byte[] encryptData(byte[] data, X509Certificate encryptionCertificate) throws CertificateEncodingException, CMSException, IOException {

byte[] encryptedData = null;
if (null != data && null != encryptionCertificate) {
    CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator
      = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();

    JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator jceKey 
      = new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(encryptionCertificate);
    cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.addRecipientInfoGenerator(transKeyGen);
    CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);
    OutputEncryptor encryptor
      = new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC)
      .setProvider("BC").build();
    CMSEnvelopedData cmsEnvelopedData = cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator
      .generate(msg,encryptor);
    encryptedData = cmsEnvelopedData.getEncoded();
}
return encryptedData;}
```

Create a JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator object using the recipient's certificate.

Then Create  a new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator object and added the recipient information generator into it.

Then use the JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder class to create an OutputEncrytor object, using the AES CBC algorithm.

The encryptor is used later to generate a CMSEnvelopedData object that encapsulates the encrypted message.

Finally, the encoded representation of the envelope is returned as a byte array.

Get the final Byte array written to a file.